# How to merge columns with same value and add values together from different columns using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mxYM.png)

Hi, I'm taking a data science course and not familiar with python.
I was wondering if it is possible to merge the same years together and adding the global sales for each year togehter?

after googling, I tried using .groupby but that didn't work, and I also tried .aggregate and it also failed.

maybe I'm using the commands wrong, or maybe I'm using the wrong commands for the task, because I'm very new to this I am not sure

Comment: What is your expected output as dataframe?

Comment: You should avoid images of tables, better add an actual formatted table to the post so people can copy it and it is easier for them to help you. Also you should make it a bit more clear what exactly you are expecting from the output. That being said, you could try something like this `df.groupby(["Year"]).agg(sum)`. This will group by year (build subgroups of rows where each member of the group has the same value in this column) and then aggregate these groups by summing them up.

Comment: Thanks for your help
I just created an account and asked my first question here, I'll be be careful for next time when asking a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `.groupby` and `.sum`.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': [2006, 2006, 2007],
  'Global_Sales': [0.7,0.8,0.9],
  'Other data': [1, 2, 3]})
```

So a test DataFrame like:

```
    Year    Global_Sales    Other data
0   2006    0.7             1
1   2006    0.8             2
2   2007    0.9             3
```

We can then `.groupby` and `.sum` and extract just the `Global_Sales` column:

```
merged = df.groupby('Year').sum()['Global_Sales']
merged.reset_index()
```

this gives:

```
    Year    Global_Sales
0   2006    1.5
1   2007    0.9
```

The `.reset_index` takes the "grouped column" which is `'Year'` here, and upgrades it from an index in the resulting DataFrame returned from `.sum()` back to a column.

Update: to remove the warning about `numeric_only`, just pre-select the relevant columns so that `.sum()` does not try other columns:

I.e.

```
df[['Year', 'Global_Sales']].groupby('Year').sum().reset_index()
```

will give the same:

```
    Year    Global_Sales
0   2006    1.5
1   2007    0.9
```

Comment: I think I got what I wanted, but when following your example I got an error which I do not understand

The error:
FutureWarning: The default value of numeric_only in DataFrameGroupBy.sum is deprecated. In a future version, numeric_only will default to False. Either specify numeric_only or select only columns which should be valid for the function.
  merged_PS3=PS3_df.groupby('Year').sum()['Global_Sales']

Comment: @zhe The code is summing all columns, including some which may not be obvious to sum, for example dates/times. Therefore you could specify `'Global_Sales'` earlier in the code -- see updated answer.